# Much kinder way of saying someone's being dramatic?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Someone is in a panic and dramatically being sensitive, confrontational, maybe a bit attention seeking.

What would one say to very concisely explain to them, to settle them, how it is they're behaving? Something far less demeaning and unhelpful than dramatic!

Comment: "That doesn't sound like the CL22 I know..."?

Comment: I like it. And similarly, for a stranger, "I'm sure you don't normally behave like this, Lord Ashworth"

Comment: No, I try to remain a gentleman.

Comment: @CL22, I **know** you can do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on workplace,se.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use - ***overreacting***

o·ver·re·act

/ˌōvə(r)rēˈakt/

verb: gerund or present participle: overreacting

**respond more emotionally or forcibly than is justified.**

"they are urging people not to overreact to the problem"

Comment: It might not be a reaction but just something spontaneous, and describing the behavior is not justified is good because it doesn't place as much blame (for better or worse). Thanks

Comment: As soon as I even read the title this was the word that popped into my head.

Answer (score 0):

I would in this case defer to using vernacular phrases or metaphors. A great line I heard in a movie (The Man from Snowy River, 1982) was "Spare me the affectations of martyrdom!".

> "Really, Jessica. You're attacking that piece with all the sensitivity
>   of a road-mender. Now, let's begin again, shall we? And this time,
>   `con amore'. And spare me the affectations of martyrdom."

[The Man From Snowy River Script](https://www.scripts.com/script/the_man_from_snowy_river_20790)

Comment: Both *affectations of martyrdom* and *sensitivity of a road-member* sound ***remarkably*** dramatic to me, if not actually insulting. This sounds like the *opposite* of what was asked for in the question. (If I heard that, I would *not* calmly settle down . . .)